# JavaScript and Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm having trouble with the following code,
I understand that I wrote something wrong but I've no idea what (tried to wrap the code with quotes but that didn't helped...)

```
var Regex = require('regex')
var regex = new Regex (/([^\s]*querySelector\w*\()(\'.*\')\2/)
```

Comment: Just use `var regex = /([^\s]*querySelector\w*\()(\'.*\')\2/;`. And what does that regex mean [`([^\s]*querySelector\w*\()(\'.*\')\2`](https://regex101.com/r/dF2mE8/1)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

`var regexp = new RegExp(/([^\s]*querySelector\w*\()(\'.*\')\2/);`

(It's `RegExp` instead of `Regex`)

Also, https://regex101.com/ is a good site which helps testing your RegExps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

var regex = new RegExp(([^\s]*querySelector\w*()(\'.*\')\2);